# Can't Deploy Sitefinity on my local machine

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I am trying to install the trail version of Sitefinity but running into this error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
________________________________________
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.ConnectorInstaller, Version=6.10.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 

Line 284:    <siteMap>
Line 285:      <providers>
Line 286:        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.ConnectorInstaller, Version=6.10.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
Line 287:      </providers>
Line 288:    </siteMap>

Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config    Line: 286 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MySql.ConnectorInstaller, Version=6.10.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

________________________________________
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2623.0
```

I see the database was made though I choose SQL Sever not mysql, so I am not sure why this error is talking about MySql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the error is coming from your machine.config file. I definitely don't have that value in neither machine.config nor the Sitefinity's web.config file.

Maybe try deleting it and restart IIS.